# How to compress all files in a directory using 7-zip?

Tags: powershell, archive, 7zip

How do you archive all files (including ones without extensions) in a directory without archiving of the subdirectories using 7-zip command tool (`7z.exe`)?

If I use the wildcard with a dot (`*.*`) it works but only for files with extensions. Using `*` (or not using the wildcard at all) does not work even with the `-r-` switch (which is supposed to be then default according to the help file), since it archives everything in the source directory recursively. I just need to archive all files (some may not have extensions) in the immediate directory (no subfolders and no recursion). Any ideas?

The following commands do not work:

```
7z.exe a c:\output.7z c:\input -r-
7z.exe a c:\output.7z c:\input\* -r-
```

I am calling 7-zip from a PowerShell script, if this matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7-Zip will take an array of file objects for the input, so this should work:

```
& 7z.exe a C:\output.7z (Get-ChildItem C:\Input\* -File)
```

Comment: Indeed (+1); worth mentioning that passing a PowerShell array to an external program such as `7z` translates to passing the array's elements as _individual arguments_. In other words: `7z` doesn't accept an _array_ as such - on the command line (outside of PowerShell), there is no concept of an _array_ - it accepts an _open-ended number of individual arguments_, as reflected in the CLI help (`7z -h`) as `<file_names>...`